# C# app with SqlClient does not work on another computer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have written an application that uses SqlClient and a local mdf database. However, it does not work on another machine (throwing an exception that the server cannot be run) and I assume this is because there is no SQL server installed? But I thought that using local database and SqlClient elimites the need for the server, something like the old SQL CE. Is that the problem?

EDIT **Exception**: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while extablishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

As for connection string, I keep the one generated by Visual Studio Express, just modify the path to use the app folder.

```
SqlConnection s = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename ="+ System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)+ @"\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
```

Is there a simple way how to rework this so that my app does not require SQL server installed? All I need is to have it use the local database file in its folder.

Comment: If, as _local database_ you mean LocalDB then you still need to install the appropriate libraries on the target machine.

Comment: Well by local database I mean a simply added a db file to the project and access it in the connection string in the app folder. Not sure now what I should add to the target machine

Comment: I usually just downvote questions which mention that *"an exception is thrown"* without including **the complete exception message and the stack trace**. Since you are new on SO, you'll get the benefit of doubt and a chance to update your question. Just don't do it again. :-) Ideally, you can create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem and post it here.

Comment: You need a server instance to attach an mdf file. What is wrong with SQL CE? It is still a thing, and is fully bin deployable.

Comment: Using a local database CAN mean that you don't need to have an instance of SQL Server installed locally.  It depends on how you construct the connection string.  We can't be sure what your issue is because you have not posted any examples of your code or exception details.  If you use a local database in the way I think you are referring, you need to 1. Make sure the database file is copied to the client and 2. Make sure that your application installs all of the required libraries on the client's machine.

Comment: Sorry: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while extablishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

Comment: Using `SqlClient` **creates** a need for the server, not eliminates it. Moreover, keeping the designer generated connection string most likely hardcodes the path to the database file. If you need a simple, file-based DB, use SQL CE or SqLite, not SQL Server.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks, well I tried but I did not find the SQL CE in VS Express 2015, just learned that it has been discontinued.

Comment: Both SQLCE and Sqlite are available on NuGet.

Comment: Updated the question with cstring.

Comment: @User039402, LocalDB is a database engine and it must be installed to use it. You have it because Visual Studio installs it. Further, your users would need an instance named MSSQLLocalDB. And, it would have to be a compatible version with your .mdf file. LocalDB is intended for development, not for production use so it is advised not to use it even if everyone has it installed or you figure out a way to install it as a prerequisite.